# How to only replace substring not entire string?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
global_dict_names=dict{'com':'owb_com','cur':'cur_con','cty':'gds_cty','cur':'gds_cur'}
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
com12  cur34  cty56  cur78
  a     b      c      d
  b     c      d      e
```

I would like my dataframe to look like this:

```
 owb_com12   cur_con34    gds_cty56    gds_cur78
  a             b            c          d
  b             c            d          e
```

My current code looks like this:

```
GDS2018_labels.columns = [global_dict_names.get(x[:3], x) for x in 
GDS2018_labels.columns]
```

This current code matches the first three characters of the column names with the keys from the dictionary. The problem with this code is that it replaces the entire column name, but I only want to replace the substring of the column name that matches with the key. How can I correct this?

Comment: Why does your dictionary have duplicate `'cur'` keys? Dictionary keys are unique.

Comment: Perhaps `[x.replace(x[:3], global_dict_names.get(x[:3], x)) for x in 
GDS2018_labels.columns]`?

Comment: So... `GDS2018_labels.columns` is - and should remain - a list?  What is `global_dict_names`?  Can you provide some (semi-)working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your input and desired output, `dict` is the wrong choice of data structure. Dictionary keys are unique, this is non-negotiable.

You can use a list of tuples and a list comprehension:

```
L = [('com', 'owb_com'), ('cur', 'cur_con'), ('cty', 'gds_cty'), ('cur', 'gds_cur')]

df.columns = [name.replace(old, new) for name, (old, new) in zip(df.columns, L)]

print(df)

  owb_com12 cur_con34 gds_cty56 gds_cur78
0         a         b         c         d
1         b         c         d         e
```

Comment: Thanks again! Why do you have to zip the columns with the dictionary?

Comment: Got my vote... I might be tempted to make it a bit more explicit such as: `[name.replace(old, new) for name, (old, new) in zip(df.columns, L)]` or similar though.

Comment: First, my solution has no dictionary. It has a list of tuples. Second, I do indeed use `zip` to iterate columns and tuples sequentially.

Comment: Thanks! Why would you prefer to use a list of tuples rather than a dictionary? (Sorry for all the questions, I'm still learning)

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. Your example has `'cur'` twice as a key. That's not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

As user jpp mentioned, you shouldn't use a dictionary as you have two equal keys. I just noticed this after posting my answer. Check his answer, if you change your dictionary to have only equal keys you can simply concatenate string by just using `+`. Add the prefix `global_dict_names.get(x[:3], x[:3])` to the suffix `x[3:]`.

```
GDS2018_labels.columns = [global_dict_names.get(x[:3], x[:3]) + x[3:] for x in 
    GDS2018_labels.columns]
```